# XMLReader not reading cdata

Tags: php, xml, nsxmlparser, xmlreader, cdata

I have a problem. I wrote this code but I can't read `<![CDATA[Epsilon Yayınları]]>`.  Items with cdata, when I get them it's empty. Is there an alternative solution?

XML:

```
<urunler>
  <urun>
    <stok_kod>9789753314930</stok_kod>
    <urun_ad><![CDATA[Kırmızı Erik]]></urun_ad>
    <Barkod>9789753314930</Barkod>
    <marka><![CDATA[Epsilon Yayınları]]></marka>
    <Kdv>8,00</Kdv>
    <satis_fiyat>9,5000</satis_fiyat>
    <kat_yolu><![CDATA[Edebiyat>Hikaye]]></kat_yolu>
    <resim>http://basaridagitim.com/images/product/9789753314930.jpg</resim>
    <Yazar>Tülay Ferah</Yazar>
    <Bakiye>2,00000000</Bakiye>
    <detay><![CDATA[]]></detay>
  </urun>
</urunler>

$xml = new XMLReader;
    $xml->open(DIR_DOWNLOAD . 'xml/'.$xml_info['xml_file_name']);
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    $product_data = array();

    $i=0;


    while ($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'urun');
    while ($xml->name === 'urun') {  $i++;

        $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(), true));


        var_dump($node->urun_ad); die();
```

Dump print:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#143 (1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#145 (0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to explain what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just comes down to how your printing out the value.  If you change the `var_dump` to either of the following, you will get what your after...

```
//var_dump($node->urun_ad)
echo $node->urun_ad.PHP_EOL;
echo $node->urun_ad->asXML().PHP_EOL;
```

outputs...

```
Kırmızı Erik
<urun_ad><![CDATA[Kırmızı Erik]]></urun_ad>
```

One thing to note is that if you want to use the value in another method, you may have to cast it to a string (echo does this automatically).  So the first one would be (for example)...

```
$urun_ad = (string)$node->urun_ad;
```

Comment: You are Hero! Thank you very sooooo much body!